# CMD for-loop, while executing via default program, and piping

Tags: for-loop, cmd

I have a directory filled with .nc files. These files have to be executed using a program called 'ncdump', which is set as the default program to open the file. It can then be executed as (output to file):

```
file.nc > output.txt
```

The file is somehow executed here. Now I want to do this for all the files in the directory using a for-loop. I tried the below:

```
for /r %i in (*) do cmd i% > scriptout.txt
```

And of course a way of numbering the outfile (with a counter no doubt) would be nice. This is probably very basic stuff but I'm rather unfamiliar with CMD (and Windows as a whole). Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for /r %%i in (*.nc) do (
    set count+=1
    %%i >scriptout!count!.txt
)
echo %count% files processed.
```

some common traps:

- in batchfiles use `%%i` (on command line only `%i`)
- to use a variable inside a block (between `(` and `)`) you have to use delayed expansion (`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to enable it and writing the variables `!var!` instead of `%var%`)
- the opening parantheses (`(`) has to be on the same line than `do` .

Comment: The second bullet point is incorrectly explained. You do **not** need to use Delayed Expansion if you want to use "a" variable inside a block. What you state between the round brackets, is actually a hint to the real reason you would need Delayed Expansion. But, that does not take away, that the sentence - without the square brackets - is false.

Comment: okay, better "if you want to use a variable, that you changed before in the same block"